# How to verify login information from two tables

Tags: node.js

I am making a login system and have two tables ""fyp_helpers " and "fyp-employers" in my MySql database.Now i want it in such a way that when user enter his number and password then it matches to both the tables and wherever it matches it just login .I don't want to create two different login forms for helpers and employers. I want to do this thing on SQL layer.**Mobile_Number and Password** are two columns in **fyp_helpers** table and **Employer_Contact** and **Employer_password** in the employer table.
This is the code but i am getting an error that is attached below

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var number = request.body.number;
    var password = request.body.pwd;
    if (number && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM fyp_helpers WHERE Mobile_number = ? AND Password = ? UNION SELECT * FROM fyp_employers WHERE Employer_Contact = ? AND Employer_Password = ?', [number, password, number, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("An error occurred:", error);
                response.send('Oops, something went wrong!');
            } else if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.number = number;
                response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                 response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            response.end();
        });

    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }

});
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but it looks like you're storing plain text passwords. Consider hashing them with a secure algorithm.

Comment: @FelipeZavan yes i will use bcrypt to hash, first i was thinking of how to login from single form thats why i posted here without hash :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an `UNION` query, the fields on both queries must match:

```
SELECT 
  fyp_helpers.Mobile_number AS number 
FROM 
  fyp_helpers 
WHERE 
  Mobile_number = ? 
  AND Password = ?
UNION 
SELECT 
  fyp_employers.Employer_Contact AS number 
FROM 
  fyp_employers 
WHERE 
  Employer_Contact = ?
  AND Employer_Password = ?
LIMIT 
  1;
```

I also added a `LIMIT` so it stops on the first result.

[Live example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w1Ez4i63nSJ79yhmUjL5bD/0)

Comment: yes i am trying it,i will surely mark it as my problem will be solved